# Object property is undefined inside event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

For some reason when I call generateTabs I get this.divRow1 is undefined.
However when I instantiate Criteria it is not undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function Criteria() {
    this.divPortfolio = $("#portfolio_div");
    this.divImport = $("#lstimprt_div");
    this.rolling = $('#rolling');
    this.datePickers = $("#datepickers");
    this.dateStart = $("#datepicker");
    this.dateEnd = $("#datepicker2");
    this.btnToggle = $("#toggle");
    this.btnRun = $("#run_report");
    this.divRow1 = $("#Row1");
    this.dateChoice = $("#datechoice");
    this.minDate = $(".minDate");
}

Criteria.prototype.generateToggle = function () {
        /** Toggle button toggle elements chosen open/closed **/
        button.click(function () {
            this.divRow1.toggle("slow");
            this.divImport.toggle("slow");
            $("#mindate_div").toggle("slow");
            $("#header_row").toggle("slow");
            return false; //Stops postback
        });
    };

    /** When page loads  **/
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var controls = new Criteria();
        var mindate = controls.minDate.html();
        controls.onloadHide();
        controls.generatePicker(controls.dateStart);
        controls.generatePicker(controls.dateEnd);
        controls.generateToggle(controls.btnToggle);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of the execution context of the callback method is not the `Criteria` object, it is the clicked button.

One solution to this is to pass a custom execution context using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
button.click($.proxy(function () {
    this.divRow1.toggle("slow");
    this.divImport.toggle("slow");
    $("#mindate_div").toggle("slow");
    $("#header_row").toggle("slow");
    return false; //Stops postback
}, this));
```

Another solution is to use a closure variable

```
var that = this;
button.click(function () {
    that.divRow1.toggle("slow");
    that.divImport.toggle("slow");
    $("#mindate_div").toggle("slow");
    $("#header_row").toggle("slow");
    return false; //Stops postback
});
```

Comment: perfect that stopped the error but for some reason only $("#mindate_div").toggle("slow"); $("#header_row").toggle("slow"); are toggling

Comment: Can you check whether the element `this.divRow1` is present?

Answer (score 1):

```
button.click(function () {
        this.divRow1.toggle("slow");
        this.divImport.toggle("slow");
        $("#mindate_div").toggle("slow");
        $("#header_row").toggle("slow");
        return false; //Stops postback
    });
```

`this` has a different scope within the click event than outside of it.  Specifically, jQuery will bind this to the item the event is being fired on (the button in this case).  If you set a breakpoint and examine `this` in the dev console at this point you'll see it refers to a DOM element.

You can get around this by setting a self variable like this, and referencing that instead.

```
Criteria.prototype.generateToggle = function () {
    var self = this;
    /** Toggle button toggle elements chosen open/closed **/
    button.click(function () {
        self.divRow1.toggle("slow");
        self.divImport.toggle("slow");
        $("#mindate_div").toggle("slow");
        $("#header_row").toggle("slow");
        return false; //Stops postback
    });
};
```

Comment: perfect that stopped the error but for some reason only $("#mindate_div").toggle("slow"); $("#header_row").toggle("slow"); are toggling

Comment: @bugz does it work if you just reference the jQuery elements directly? Its tough to tell you exactly why since we can't see your markup and don't know what `controls.onloadHide();` does.  On the surface I don't see any reason why a valid jQuery call wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria.prototype.generateToggle = function () {

        var that = this; 
        /** Toggle button toggle elements chosen open/closed **/
        button.click(function () {

            that.divRow1.toggle("slow");
            that.divImport.toggle("slow");
            $("#mindate_div").toggle("slow");
            $("#header_row").toggle("slow");
            return false; //Stops postback
        });
    };
```

The "this" context has changed inside the button click. Try the above